# Redundant space in page problem in Flutter

Tags: flutter, stack

//SOLVED: one of the containers inside the stack had an margin attribute that margins symetrically. Changed it to EdgeInsets.only(left:..,top:..)

I want to let my ListView start after the blue part of my page. But there is an blank and redundant space that doesn't allow me to start at expected point.

[the blank space that i get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VZZA3.png)

Here is my code:

```
Column(children:[Stack(some other code),Expanded(child:ListView(..))]);
```

Comment: Tested , but failed to reproduce the same error, can include full widget.

Comment: Full Widget tree is: Scaffold -> SafeArea -> Column - Stack and Expanded in Column and the child of Expanded is ListView

Comment: Every widget contains unique properties, can you just share code snippet that will reproduce the errors?

Answer (score 0):

The space is there because you have wrapped `Stack(some other code)` inside `Column`.
This is what you should do if you want the `ListView` to be over `some other code`, ​

```
Stack(
 ​children:[
   //some other code,
   Column(
     ​children:[
       ​Expanded(
         child : ListView(...)
       ),
...
```

Comment: I dont want to ListView to be over some other code. I just want to remove blank place between stack and listview.

Comment: The stack is consuming that space. Removing that stack will remove the blank space, @bach.

Comment: I thought the same but It is a blank space. How can it be possible? There is no white container. Do you have an idea?

Comment: Are you saying that even after removing the entire `Stack`, there is a padding?

Comment: Yes i got same problem

Comment: That's weird. Do consider editing your question with more of your code.

Answer (score 0):

According to [documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ListView-class.html):

> By default, ListView will automatically pad the list's scrollable extremities to avoid partial obstructions indicated by MediaQuery's padding. To avoid this behavior, override with a zero padding property.

To remove it wrap the `ListView` into a `MediaQuery.removePadding`:

```
MediaQuery.removePadding(
    context: context,
    removeTop: true,
    child: ListView(...))
```

Comment: Sorry It doesn't work. Here is the error message that i got: " Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════
RenderBox was not laid out: RenderRepaintBoundary#ecc4b relayoutBoundary=up3 NEEDS-PAINT
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
Failed assertion: line 1930 pos 12: 'hasSize'
"

Comment: Can you update your question with your current code? This error does not seem to be related to the padding above `ListView`.